# How to get a radio button or sheet macro to use relative references

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a radio button to add or subtract from the on hands in the same row. I couldn't figure out how to tie it down to a cell.

I decided to just fill E2-E450 and F2-F450 with a "+" or "-" sign respectively.
I want when you click E2 it adds + 1 to D2 or when you click F3 it subtracts one from D3 and so on and so forth.

```vb
Sub MyMacro()
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("D2") + 1
End Sub


Sub MyMacro2()
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("D2") - 1
End Sub
```

For the sheet this is what I have

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro
        End If
    End If

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro2
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What does your sheet actually look like?  It's not clear from your question exactly what you want to happen. What you want the sheet to look like with radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Each button is assigned to the OptionButtonClick procedure below, which is stored in a normal module.  Clicking the button will return the address of the TopLeftCell that the button is sitting in.

[Application.Caller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Caller) will return the name of the shape that was clicked.

```
Public Sub OptionButtonClick()

    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address

End Sub
```

I would give a more detailed answer, but I've no idea what the "on hands" are.

Comment: so Basically I have columns A-F. Column D contains the quantity on hand of any given item. IE: I currently have 6 gaskets in stock. So the value in D2 is "6". 

I want it to be that when I click on E2 it adds "+1" to that value (=7) or when I click on F2 it subtracts "-1" from that value (=5).

I have 450 rows in total and I want the Macro's for +/- to work for each row. So clicking F3 should modify D3. Or clicking F5 should modify D5. Currently they all only change the value of D2 and I don't know how to fix it